# How to use more than 2 versions on jquery?

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I want to use bootstrap theme and it requires jquery 1.9, but when I set 1.9, ajax enabled views do not work. I am using views 3.14. There are few contrib modules which require older version of jquery. So in jquery_update I can set "default drupal" for admin pages and 1.7 for the site.

How to get 1.9 as well for my site with no conflicts?

I have found [jquery multi](https://drupal.org/project/jqmulti) module during search, but do not know if it is what I am looking for.

Secondly, Can I use this module with [jquery update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) enabled?

Comment: Worth noting that the answer to this can be found on the project page of the jQuery multi module.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to run multiple versions of jQuery for different contrib modules I would say the [jQuery multi](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqmulti) module would be the easiest solution (although I don't know the specifics of your requirements).

The 7.x-2.x branch of jQuery update is supported with jQuery multi.

For example, you could use Drupal default jQuery for admin pages, jQuery 1.7 for non-admin pages and jQuery 1.9 for the specific plugins/modules that require it.
Or alternatively you can use 1.9 as the main version and 1.7 for specific plugins/modules.
Whichever works best for your site.

Usage instructions for the jQuery multi module can be found in its README.txt file when you download it.